Leaflet Map with Angular 19 not shown
I tried to update my application from ng18 to 19, but now my Map isn't shown anymore despite all elements being in the DOM tree.
I'm using leaflet 1.9.4 with @types/leaflet 1.9.15.
Both .js and .css are set in angular.json. Without the .css included I can see the tiles  appearing out of place and my markers floating in the air, but as soon as I add .css in angular.json, nothing (including the map markers) is displayed anymore.
I can verify that .css is also loaded correctly as part of my styles.scss.
I can also reproduce the same issue with this different setup:
index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <title>Test19</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>

</head>
<body>
   <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>

app.component.ts:
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as Leaflet from 'leaflet';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<div #map class="map"></div>`,
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('map') public mapDiv!: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const l = Leaflet.map(this.mapDiv.nativeElement, { center: [0, 0], zoom: 1 });
    const t = Leaflet.tileLayer('http://localhost:8081/worldmap/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}', { maxZoom: 6, minZoom: 1, noWrap: true });
    t.addTo(l);
  }
}

am I missing something or does the angular 19 update break leaflet?
Is there any known fix or workaround?
if my Browser plays a role here: Firefox 130.0
Edit:
With .css enabled (both by index.html and angular.json)

you can see the tiles are loaded. This is a 2x2 map size with tiles 1/0/0 and 1/1/0 being on the upper row and tiles 1/0/1 and 1/1/1 being the lower.
The hovered tile is 1/0/1 which should be on the lower row, the upper row is shifted upwards out of the screen. The given img link works, I can drag the entire  above the div where it sais map leaflet-container and the tile then becomes visible.

What happens if you open your dev tools / resize the browser window?

@JamesP tiles out of place is just due to missing Leaflet CSS. OP mentions it as a debugging step, proving that the CSS is correctly loaded.

@ghybs without css: the out of place tiles wander approx 30% down the page with every rescale. With css enabled: nothing to see, but the position of the tiles are adjusted correctly, although the center of the map tiles are set to the upper border of the screen. (I added a picture to my question) I'm fairly certain this has something to do with angular 19 as downgrading made everything look right again. Maybe they changed how css is capsuled, but I also tried to disable view encapsulation for the component.
